# Grafana candlestick display as vertical line when using postgresql datasource

Tags: grafana, candlestick-chart

When I select datasource from postgresql datasource with the following sql, then candlestick viaualization display as vertical line instead of candlestick. Anyone knows why?

```
SELECT server_ts, open, high, low, close FROM data WHERE stock_name = 'xxxx' LIMIT 50
```

[image]